# Checking Firebase children for largest to smallest values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have React app which displays name from a Firebase database and orders them in two columns -- Trending Up (highest number of downvotes on top) and Trending Down (lowest number of votes on top.) Each name in the database has a `votes` value, which can be any number (total of user's upvotes - user's downvotes)

[image]

I have these names being loaded to my page and ordered by `most votes` in the left column, and `least votes` in the right column (Trending Up, and Trending Down) which is working just fine.

[image: current view]

To the left of each person's name I have a badge with a number, which I would like to simply be their rank number. In this case, going off the database above, Darnold will be 1, Jackson will be 2, Chubb would be 4, and Rosen would be 3. Right now, I have a 1 hardcoded for everyone.

My question is what would be the best way to query the database to look through the names and assign a rank number to the player, depending on largest number of votes and least amount of votes? One thing that will need to be taken into account is if I have multiple people with the same number of votes (which will happen frequently), they will need to have the same number, i.e. If Darnold is 2, and Jackson is 2, they will both be 1 rank in this above example, and the next person will be rank 3, etc,.

Some of the code:

```
render(props){
    return(
        <div className="player fade-in">
            <span className="badges">1</span>
            <p className="playerContent">{this.playerContent}</p>
            <span>
            <span className={`vote up ${this.state.votedUp === true && 'alreadyVotedUp'}`}
            onClick={() => this.handleUpvote(this.playerId)}>
            &#9650;
            </span>
            <br/>
            <span className={`vote down ${this.state.votedDown === true && 'alreadyVotedDown'}`}
            onClick={() => this.handleDownvote(this.playerId)}>
            &#9660;
            </span>
            </span>

        </div>
    )
}
```

---

Here's how my players are being shown and ordered to the screen, using lodash.

const orderedPlayersUp = _.orderBy(players, ['votes'], ['desc']).filter(p => p.votes >= 0);

```
          orderedPlayersUp.map((player) => {
            return (
              <Player
                playerContent={player.playerContent}
                playerId={player.id}
                key={player.id}
                upvotePlayer={this.upvotePlayer}
                downvotePlayer={this.downvotePlayer}
                userLogIn={this.userLogIn}
                userLogOut={this.userLogOut}
                uid={this.uid}
              />
            )
          })
```

If other relevant code is needed please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this isn't working perfectly, and I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way, but it is working ok currently.

```
let rankCount = 1
```

---

```
const orderedPlayersRank = _.orderBy(players, ['votes'], ['desc'])


orderedPlayersRank.map((player) => {
            this.database.child(player.id).transaction(function(player) {
              if (player.votes >= prevPlayerVotes) {
                prevPlayerVotes = player.votes
                player.rank = rankCount
              }
              else if(player.votes < prevPlayerVotes){
                rankCount++
                player.rank = rankCount
                prevPlayerVotes = player.votes
              }
              else{
                console.log("Rank calculation error.")
              }
              return player;
            })
          })
```

Outcome:

[image: db]

For some reason I need to refresh the page (sometimes twice) for the render to show the correct rank, but the code is doing it's job and distinguishing ties and higher/lower ranks.

[image]